# Cannot install Puma gem on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, puma

I'm trying to install the puma gem, but when I run

```
gem install puma
```

I get this error message:

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing puma:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make                                                
generating puma_http11-i386-mingw32.def                              
compiling http11_parser.c       
ext/http11/http11_parser.rl: In function 'puma_parser_execute':  
ext/http11/http11_parser.rl:111:3: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer   expressions    
compiling io_buffer.c   
io_buffer.c: In function 'buf_to_str':             
io_buffer.c:119:3: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 1 of 'rb_str_new'      differ in signedness             
c:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/intern.h:653:7: note: expected 'const char *' but argument is of type 'uint8_t *'                    
compiling mini_ssl.c                                         
In file included from mini_ssl.c:3:0:                                        
c:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward/rubyio.h:2:2: warning: #warning use "ruby/io.h" instead of "rubyio.h"              
mini_ssl.c:4:25: fatal error: openssl/bio.h: No such file or directory               
compilation terminated.                     
make: *** [mini_ssl.o] Error 1             

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/puma-2.6.0 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/puma-2.6.0/ext/puma_http11/gem_make.out
```

Adding `gem 'puma'` to my Gemfile and running `bundle install` isn't an option, because that just doesn't work with any gem and gives me an error message (which is a separate issue, one that I've circumvented with the other gems I've used by installing them via `gem install`).

Comment: It sounds like you might not have the openssl headers installed for your platform. Check out [puma issue GH#202](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/202) for links to OpenSSL headers for Windows.

Comment: try `gem install puma --source http://rubygems.org`

Comment: I ran `bundle update` before `bundle install` and that solved the issue.
I'm not sure if that was the only thing that helped, as I manually downloaded openssl and `gem install puma -- --with-opt-dir=c:/RailsInstaller/openssl`

`ruby -v -ropenssl -e "puts OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION"`

Answer (score 15):

Came across very same issue.

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

fixed it for me.

Comment: The OP is using windows, not linux.

Comment: But, this was helpful for me.

Answer (score 12):

I ran `bundle update` before `bundle install` and that solved the issue for me.

I'm not sure if that was the only thing that helped, as I manually updated puma before that, using these steps:

1. Checked which version of openssl Ruby is using by running `ruby -v -ropenssl -e "puts OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION"`
2. Downloaded the right openssl version from
   http://packages.openknapsack.org/openssl/openssl-1.0.0o-x86-windows.tar.lzma
   (got the link from https://github.com/hicknhack-software/rails-disco/wiki/Installing-puma-on-windows and edited it based on the output of #1).
3. Extracted openssl using http://www.7-zip.org to C:\RailsInstaller\openssl
4. `gem install puma -- --with-opt-dir=C:/RailsInstaller/openssl`

Comment: I think it was the manual update. I followed those steps and it worked. Note that it's important to use forward slashes (`C:/RailsInstaller/openssl`) instead of backslashes (`C:\RailsInstaller\openssl`).

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to go hunting for a 64-bit version of openssl as I'm using 64-but Ruby etc. For reference, I found it here: https://bintray.com/artifact/download/oneclick/OpenKnapsack/x64/openssl-1.0.1l-x64-windows.tar.lzma

Answer (score 6):

Figured out the solution to the puma bundle. Followed directions from https://github.com/hicknhack-software/rails-disco/wiki/Installing-puma-on-windows

First you need to download:

- [DevKit](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/) compatible with your ruby version
- [OpenSSL](http://packages.openknapsack.org/openssl/openssl-1.0.0k-x86-windows.tar.lzma) Developer Package (contains header files and binaries)

And then:

- Install DevKit, e.g. in `c:\devkit`
- Unpack the OpenSSL Package, e.g. in `c:\openssl` (use 7Zip or PeaZip)
- You need to copy the ddls from the bin directory (`libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll`) to your ruby/bin directory.
- Open a windows console
- Initialize the DevKit build environment: `c:\devkit\devkitvars.bat` (except here, I used this in command prompt instead: `ruby dk.rb init`)

Now it’s possible to install the puma gem with the OpenSSL packages:

```
gem install puma -- --with-opt-dir=c:\openssl
```

Comment: This solution worked for me. Just in case someone need detail:
`gem install puma -v '2.9.1' -- --with-opt-dir=c:\openssl`
`bundle install`

Comment: ruby/bin already had the 2 dlls on my system, I tried to overwrite them with the ones in openssl and ruby started to complain about openssl support. Reverted to the original files and everything worked fine, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I think you hit issue #430
https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/430

Re-installing Ruby might help you as well as it closed this issue on GitHub.