# Puma installation error on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, openssl, puma

I am trying to install puma gem on Windows machine. I am getting the following error. Went through a couple of forums but in vain.

```
C:/railsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb 
creating Makefile

make
generating puma_http11-i386-mingw32.def
compiling http11_parser.c
ext/http11/http11_parser.rl: In function 'puma_parser_execute':
ext/http11/http11_parser.rl:111:3: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions
compiling io_buffer.c
io_buffer.c: In function 'buf_to_str':
io_buffer.c:119:3: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 1 of 'rb_str_new' differ in signedness
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:668:7: note: expected 'const char *' but argument is of type 'uint8_t *'
compiling mini_ssl.c
In file included from mini_ssl.c:3:0:
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/backward/rubyio.h:2:2: warning: #warning use "ruby/io.h" instead of "rubyio.h"
mini_ssl.c:4:25: fatal error: openssl/bio.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [mini_ssl.o] Error 1
```

I have tried to install openSSL Headers packages and libraries as mentioned on https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/202 , the links don't work.

Comment: This has been a big issue for Window users. Check out [this](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/202) and [this](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/424).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot install Puma gem on Ruby on Rails.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20294199/cannot-install-puma-gem-on-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ran `bundle update` before `bundle install` and that solved the issue for me.

I'm not sure if that was the only thing that helped, as I manually updated puma before that, using these steps:

1. Checked which version of openssl Ruby is using by running `ruby -v -ropenssl -e "puts OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION"`
2. Downloaded the right openssl version from
   http://packages.openknapsack.org/openssl/openssl-1.0.0o-x86-windows.tar.lzma
   (got the link from https://github.com/hicknhack-software/rails-disco/wiki/Installing-puma-on-windows and edited it based on the output of #1).
3. Extracted openssl using http://www.7-zip.org to C:\RailsInstaller\openssl
4. `gem install puma -- --with-opt-dir=C:/RailsInstaller/openssl`

Comment: Glad you found this helpful!

Comment: unbelievable! until now i thought, puma didn't support windows. Thanks for the writeup.