# Getting Error while installing puma extension in Ruby on Rails on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, puma

**I was trying to install puma extension in Ruby on Rails and getting this error.**

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb 
creating Makefile

make
generating puma_http11-i386-mingw32.def
compiling http11_parser.c
ext/http11/http11_parser.rl: In function 'puma_parser_execute':
ext/http11/http11_parser.rl:111:3: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions
compiling io_buffer.c
io_buffer.c: In function 'buf_to_str':
io_buffer.c:119:3: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 1 of 'rb_str_new' differ in signedness
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/intern.h:661:7: note: expected 'const char *' but argument is of type 'uint8_t *'
compiling mini_ssl.c
In file included from mini_ssl.c:3:0:
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward/rubyio.h:2:2: warning: #warning use "ruby/io.h" instead of "rubyio.h"
mini_ssl.c:4:25: fatal error: openssl/bio.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [mini_ssl.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't have OpenSSL installed or properly configured.

Check these for more info.

[Cannot install Puma gem on Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20294199/cannot-install-puma-gem-on-ruby-on-rails)

Also the issue on Puma Github Repository

https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/430

Answer (score 2):

Use the --with-opt-dir to specify the OpenSSL install location:

```
gem install puma -- --with-opt-dir=c:\openssl
```

I was also trying this in MINGW32 (like the linux utils provided with git), and found that you must use a forward slash in MINGW:

```
gem install puma -- --with-opt-dir=c:/openssl
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gem install puma -- --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
```