# ERROR: Error installing puma: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, puma

I know there are several related posts, I have tried several solutions.

I have reviewed and tried soulutions from:

[Cannot install Puma gem on Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20294199/cannot-install-puma-gem-on-ruby-on-rails),
puma issues 202 on github,
puma issues 424 on github, and
hicknhack-software/rails-disco/wiki/Installing-puma-on-windows
and a few other sources, I cannot post full links because I have no rep.

I am aware of the need to download openssl and reference it in the gem install command. I have downloaded and tried with various versions of openssl, the last one I used is 1040064 openssl-1.0.2a-i386-win32.zip from http://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/

I am running:
version of ruby = ruby 2.0.0p598 (2014-11-13) [i386-mingw32]
version of rails = 4.1.8 
 
Windows 7, 64 bit

Full Error:

```
Jon@JON-PC /c/with_forked_on_4_8 (master)
$ gem install puma -- --with-opt-dir=c:\openssl
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions with: '--with-opt-dir=c:openssl'
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing puma:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb --with-opt-dir=c:openssl

checking for BIO_read() in -lcrypto... no
checking for BIO_read() in -llibeay32... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/bin/ruby
        --with-puma_http11-dir
        --without-puma_http11-dir
        --with-puma_http11-include
        --without-puma_http11-include=${puma_http11-dir}/include
        --with-puma_http11-lib
        --without-puma_http11-lib=${puma_http11-dir}/
        --with-cryptolib
        --without-cryptolib
        --with-libeay32lib
        --without-libeay32lib


Gem files will remain installed in    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0
.0/gems/puma-2.11.1 for inspection.
Results logged to c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/puma-2.11
.1/ext/puma_http11/gem_make.out
```

Comment: There's absolutely no way for anyone to know based on that output. You see that line where it tells you "Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details."?  Maybe try checking the mkmf.log file for details and posting them here.  But I'd also make it clear in your title that you are building on windows.  Someone's probably going to need some windows expertise to help you with this native compilation problem. Or try googling for building puma on windows, eg https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/202