# RoR in Windows not working for pre-existing app built with RoR in linux

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3, windows-8

I've installed Ruby on Rails using RailsInstaller and also postgresql in Windows 8.  I'm trying to run `rails server` using files for a pre existing app but I'm getting the error 'Worker mode not supported on JRuby or Windows'.

In my config/puma.rb file i've set workers to 0, then get an error about daemon mode not supported on windows. basically each time i change something i get more errors.

I've fixed up environment variables, gems, etc (like in other posts) such as this [Cannot install Puma gem on Ruby on Rails.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20294199/cannot-install-puma-gem-on-ruby-on-rails..is) there any hope of running a pre-existing RoR app built in linux on a windows machine?

When I run rails server for the RoR 'blog' example it works fine, so I know that RoR is definitely working in windows!

This is my -'de-identified' config/puma.rb file.  Is it because in windows I have no /var/app folder?? I've played around with directories etc to no avail.

```
`
#!/usr/bin/env puma

# start puma with:
# RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec puma -C ./config/puma.rb

workers 0
theident = 'nameofthing'
application_path =  '/var/app/'+ theident + '.address.com.au/current'
railsenv = 'production'
directory application_path
environment railsenv
daemonize false
pidfile "#{application_path}/tmp/pids/puma-#{railsenv}.pid"
state_path "#{application_path}/tmp/pids/puma-#{railsenv}.state"
stdout_redirect"#{application_path}/log/puma-#{theident}.log"
threads 0, 16
bind "unix:///var/run/puma/" + theident + "_app.sock" `
```

I have changed those directories to the current path and now running 'rails server' starts going , but localhost:3000 is a page not working. I am getting errors around SIGUSR1 not working , SIGUSR2 not working ,etc

Answer (score 1):

The "workers" method isn't supported for JRuby nor Windows, so the best solution would be to **remove the line from puma.rb causing the error**. In my case I removed;

```
workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2)
```

So remaining I have;

```
threads_count = Integer(ENV['RAILS_MAX_THREADS'] || 5)
threads threads_count, threads_count

preload_app!

rackup      DefaultRackup
port        ENV['PORT']     || 3000
environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'

on_worker_boot do
  # Worker specific setup for Rails 4.1+
  # See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server#on-worker-boot
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

It might be different for you, but the specific line will start with "workers"

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - in the end I had to remove the puma gem from my gemfile and install node js before getting it to work!